# shell: set variables just before command

Tags: shell

```
HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console hadoop fs -text /foo/bar
```

This is a sample shell command. What's the exact meaning of the shell grammar (set variable just before command)?

Comment: Recall, all subshells inherit their environment from the parent process. `HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console` simply adds an variable that will be part of the subshell environment without also lingering in the parents environment after `command` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the value of that variable in the environment of the command you are running, without permanently affecting the environment of your shell.

Comment: foo=bar echo $foo                    

This prints empty. why doesn't this print bar?

Comment: @newbee Because `$foo` is expanded by the shell before passing it to `echo`.  `echo` is even a builtin command in bash, and as such I'm not 100% sure if it sees the updated environment.  Try this:  `foo=bar perl -e 'print $ENV{foo},"\n"'`